# Do I need one or many sarama.SyncProducer inside my Golang app?

Tags: go, sarama

I am new in Golang, I need to write the app that will publish events to kafka,  I can't find the answers on the following questions:

1. How many sarama.SyncProducer do I need?
2. Is it fine to use one across all app? Shall I have some kind of producer pool?

Comment: From offical github repo: One important thing to note is that both the SyncProducer and AsyncProducer are thread-safe. Go's http.Server handles requests concurrently in different goroutines, but you can use a single producer safely. This will actually achieve efficiency gains as the producer will be able to batch messages from concurrent requests together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you get the data to be published on a much higher rate than the publisher can publish it (?), given the sarama publisher is [asynchronous and concurrent](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/wiki/Producer-implementation) , I'd say you don't need more than one publisher. So to answer straight your questions:

1. I'd go with one, without knowing your requirements.
2. Yes. I'd imagine it's more likely that one needs a pool of consumers, given of course, there's high rate of messages being published.

Comment: So, seems like I need one AsyncProducer instead :)

Comment: I would say so without knowing your specific requirements, but also based on my current (~3 years) experience with sarama & kafka :)

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on how your app works. In most of the case, one producer is enough. It can interact with many topics... I let you read the [example](https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama#example-SyncProducer)
2. Yes, that's very good. You can see the producer as the exit door of your application.

But, you should use an asynchronous producer. Sarama is asynchronous if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`SyncProducer` or `AsyncProducer` return a producer struct with connection to broker defined in sarama.Config.

1. How many sarama.SyncProducer do I need?

> You need only one producer struct with initialized configurations to set to multiple brokers.

2. Is it fine to use one across all app? Shall I have some kind of
   producer pool ?

> There is nothing like one producer can be used across all app. The only thing is it
>   you can connect to same broker using the same configurations. Because if there is a different app you need to create a new producer with similar configurations.